# Is checkpointing mandatory when using a Kafka sink in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to use Spark Structured Streaming to write aggregated data to Kafka. Here's my code:

```
dataset
    .writeStream()
    .queryName(queryName)
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers)
    .option("topic", "topic")
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("15 seconds"))
    // .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
    .start();
```

If I comment out `checkpointLocation`, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: checkpointLocation must be specified either through option("checkpointLocation", ...) or SparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", ...);
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$3.apply(StreamingQueryManager.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$3.apply(StreamingQueryManager.scala:205)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:282)
    at <myClass>)
```

Is checkpointing mandatory when using a Kafka sink? I could not find an answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The checkpointing is needed to keep track what exactly was processed and written to a sink.

Let's assume you have a bunch of files in an input folder. When you start a stream spark starts processing files from source. To be sure that these files are processed and written to a sink only once it uses checkpointing where all progress information is stored.

In other words, checkpointing is needed not for the sink but for the entire stream to make sure that the same input data won't be processed over and over again.

Comment: That makes sense, however when I use a ForeachSink or a ConsoleSink checkpointing doesn't seem to be mandatory.

Comment: The options specified on a WriteStream are passing to the sink implementation and it seems for Kafka it was decided to make checkpointing mandatory, however I don't know the reason (probably because of the nature of Kafka streams).
ForEach and Console sinks can easily work without checkpointing. It just means when you restart the app it will process the same source data again.